# I stood and smoked them all

Tags: meaning

*Then a great deal of time passed as I stood in front of a pipe shop and looked, and the whole world faded except that window and I stood and smoked **them** all, and saw myself a great author with that natty Italian briar, and a cane, stepping out of a big black car, and she was there too, proud as hell of me, the lady in the silver fox fur.*

Source: John Fante: Ask the dust.

Could you tell me please to which noun the pronoun "them" is related in the clause above. There is no plural noun preceding "them".

Comment: The pipes? He's looking at the window of a pipe shop and imagines his life as a great author, wealthy, with the woman of his dreams by his side, smoking (e.g. owning) all the pipes in the shop window.

Comment: That's an interesting one. As laureapresa and catija say, the answer is that "them" refers to the pipes in the window of the shop. But he never actually mentions such pipes. You have to infer their existence from the fact that he mentions the window of a pipe shop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's talking about the pipes in the window of the pipe shop.

Imagine that this is the front window of the shop:

[image: Pipe Shop]

The man is staring into the window imagining himself using the pipes in the window.

As a note "Italian Briar" is a type of tree [pipes are often made of](http://www.pipesandcigars.com/faq/article/125/why-briar-and-not-something-else).

> Briar is the burlwood of the white heath tree, which grows in the region surrounding the Mediterranean Sea. Areas that are known for briar production are Corsica, Italy, Spain, France and Algeria, among others. The burl grows underground, between the root and the trunk of the tree. In the past, the whole tree was harvested to get the burls, but today we have methods for excising the burl while allowing the tree to keep growing.